# Swift Timer lags

Tags: swift, macos, timer, nstimer

I know `Timer` is not guaranteed to run at exactly the rate you asked for.
However, I have just started an all new project with this:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var timer = Timer()
    var count: Double = 0.0
    var timeStamp: Date = Date()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1,
                                      target: self,
                                      selector: #selector(self.updateCounting),
                                      userInfo: nil,
                                      repeats: true)
}

@objc func updateCounting(){
    let duration = self.timeStamp.distance(to: Date())
    print("Counting \(self.count) vs. Real life \(duration)")
    self.count = self.count + 0.1
}
```

}

I am expecting to get roughly the same results between `count` and `duration` but I see strange things like this:

```
Counting 60.50000000000059 vs. Real life 60.64057409763336
Counting 60.60000000000059 vs. Real life 60.741435050964355
Counting 60.70000000000059 vs. Real life 70.84065008163452
Counting 60.800000000000594 vs. Real life 80.94094407558441
Counting 60.900000000000595 vs. Real life 82.99448704719543
```

Tested on Xcode 11.5, on iMac and MacBook Pro.
Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not wrong, but you missed the *Energy Efficiency Guide for Mac Apps*:

- [Prioritize Work at the App Level](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/PrioritizeWorkAtTheAppLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013929-CH36-SW1)
- [Prioritize Work at the Task Level](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/PrioritizeWorkAtTheTaskLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013929-CH35-SW1)
- [Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/BestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013929-CH38-SW1)

Your app was just napping.

Check the [`ProcessInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo) & search for *Managing Activities*. An example (bad one) is to change your `AppDelegate.swift` to:

```swift
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    private var activity: NSObjectProtocol!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let options: ProcessInfo.ActivityOptions = [.userInitiatedAllowingIdleSystemSleep]
        let reason = "No napping!"
        self.activity = ProcessInfo.processInfo.beginActivity(options: options, reason: reason)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        ProcessInfo.processInfo.endActivity(activity)
    }
}
```

But don't do this, it's bad for users, MacBook Pro battery life, etc.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer and the links. Coming from iOS, I was not aware of this. As this macOS app is for internal use, only my own MacBook's battery will suffer ;).